# VS Code git revert change inline within submodules fails

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, inline, git-submodules, git-revert

I still have the same problem as described in following issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177453

However, looks it was fixed here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/177691

My VS Code version is as follows:

> Version: 1.81.1 (system setup)
> Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
> Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
> Electron: 22.3.18
> ElectronBuildId: 22689846
> Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
> Node.js: 16.17.1
> V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

What should I do to have this feature working in VS Code?
I would like to know if there is any setting or any VS Code version fixing this feature.

Let me give you another reference more:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176051

Comment: if you suspect a feature regression, then I'd suggest raising a new issue ticket and linking to the previous related ones you found. If you do, please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: Thanks @starball for helping with this. It is my first time managing issues in stack overflow. Actually, I'm not sure if it is due to a feature regression or maybe something that I haven't configured properly yet, because I dont know much about this, sorry.